# Kronecker simple extension: problem with use of isomorphism

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to prove that for a field $K$ and irreducible $f \in K[x]$, there exists a simple algebraic extension of $K$ with a root of $f$ as a defining element (i.e., that there is a field $F$ of which $K$ is a subfield such that $F = K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in F$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$). I understand that the assumption that $f$ is irreducible over $K$ can be assumed without loss of generality. Furthermore, I know that $K[x]/(f)$ is a field as $f$ is irreducible over $K$; where \begin{align*} H = \{ [k] = k + (f) : k \in K\}, \end{align*} I also have that $H \cong K$ via the map $H \to K$ defined by $[k] \mapsto k$, and I know that $H$ is a subfield of $K[x]/(f)$, so $K[x]/(f)$ is an extension of $H$. What I do not understand is ***why*** numerous texts subsequently say that, as a result of this isomorphism, **"we may thus identify $H$ with $K$ and so may view $K[x]/(f)$ as an extension of $K$"**. Can someone explain this to me as thoroughly as possible? I would feel much more comfortable if I had some result which produced some extension **of K** that is, e.g., isomorphic to the extension $K[x]/(f)$ of $H (\cong K)$. I have elsewhere seen the same inference not from the isomorphism between $H$ and $K$ but simply from the fact that there is an injective homomorphism between them. Any clarification as to why the isomorphic copy of $K$ is treated as **the actual base field K for the extension K[x]/(f)** would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First assume that $\deg(f)\geq 1$. Now notice that we have a chain of canonical maps, the first being inclusion and the latter being the quotient map:

$$K\hookrightarrow K[x]\to K[x]/(f)$$

Now $H=\{k+(f)|k\in K\}$ is just the image of $K$ in the above composite map. Notice that this composite map has to be injective because if two elements $r_1+(f)$ and $r_2+(f)$ are equivalent, this means that $r_1-r_2\in (f)$ which is ridiculous since the degree of $r_1-r_2$ in $K[x]$ is $0$ and $f$ has degree at least one.

Maybe this concrete example will help: The complex numbers should be thought of as the real numbers augmented by $i$. What is $i$? It is just an element $x$ that satisfies $x^2+1=0$, so we may identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

In this defintion of $\mathbb C$, what is $\mathbb R$? If we set $f=x^2+1$, $\mathbb R$ is just the subfield given by $\{r+(f):r\in \mathbb R \}$.

To summarize, to add a solution to some equation to your existing field $F$, just adjoin an indeterminate $x$ to obtain $F[x]$ and quotient out by whatever polynomial $f$ you want it to satisfy to obtain $F[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Thank you! One quick, possibly stupid question... what is the map $K \to K[x]$? The only one with which I'm familiar is the "evaluate-at" map using some particular element of $K$ (or some extension of $K$)... is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Not quite. $K[x]$ is all polynomials in one variable over $x$ with coefficients in $K$. So expressions like $a_0+a_1x+\cdots a_n x^n$. The degree $0$ polynomials are exactly the constants, i.e. elements of $K$. This is the implicit identification that I just wrote out as a map. The evaluation map $f(x)\mapsto f(0)$ that you are thinking about goes the other way $K[x]\to K$.

Comment: Ok, I am fully on board with the composite map you gave in your first comment: $H = \{k + (f) : k \in K\}$ is the image of $K$ under this map and is contained in $K[x]/(f)$. I also understand your analogy with respect to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\left<x^{2}+1\right>$. Could you please relate that analogy to how we can, in the present case, identify $H$ with $K$ (and thus identify the extension $K[x]/(f)$ of $H$ with the base field $K$)? How is this related to the fact that the composite map is an injective homomorphism?